# Failed to visualize the MODIS fire data based on the uncertainty difference on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I want to visualize the MODIS burn area data according to the differences in the uncertainty level, creating one layer with all the recorded burn area, while the other layer shows the burn area with uncertainty <30%.

Below is my code. However, the resulting map shows there are no differences between two layers I attempted to create. Kindly want to know where the problem is based on the code below.
Here is the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f7e6150a8875ffdc61170d9a501157f8

```
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1")
          .filter(ee.Filter.or(
            ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Syrian Arab Republic'),
            ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Iraq'),
            ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Iran  (Islamic Republic of)'),
            ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Turkey')
          ));

//Load the MODIS burn area data and filter the uncertainty
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD64A1')
                .filterDate('2000-12-31', '2023-12-31')
                .filterBounds(ROI)
                .map(function(image){return image.clip(ROI)})
                .map(function(img){
                  var thr = img.select('Uncertainty').lt(30);
                  return img.updateMask(thr)
                  .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())
                  })
                print(dataset)

//Load the MODIS burn area data without filtering the uncertainty               
var dataset1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD64A1')
                .filterDate('2000-12-31', '2023-12-31')
                .filterBounds(ROI)
                .map(function(image){return image.clip(ROI)})
                print(dataset1)



//make a comparison between original data and the data with >70% confidence level
// original pixels
var burnedArea_original = dataset1.select('BurnDate');
// pixels with uncertainty < 30
var burnedArea_Uncertainty_30 = dataset.select('BurnDate');

// visualize the original burn area data
Map.addLayer(burnedArea_original, {palette: ['3386FF']}, 'Burned Area Original');
// visualize the burn area with uncertainty < 30%
Map.addLayer(burnedArea_Uncertainty_30, {palette: ['FF3333']}, 'Burned Area with Uncertainty < 30%');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly. If you look at the [MCD64A1 User Guide](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/1006/MCD64_User_Guide_V61.pdf), uncertainty measures the possible error in the burn day, *not* the level of confidence that it burned:

> Burn Date Uncertainty: Estimated uncertainty in date of burn, in days.

None of the pixels in that area have uncertainty > 30 days. If you change the threshold to 2 or 3 days you'll start to see some differences.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see the difference by setting 2, 3. However, I wonder then why the 'uncertainty' value range is from 0 to 100 because it's impossible to have it over 16 (days).